# Wanting to sift through two tables to find common names and associated data. Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

Good day all. Spent the last few weeks lurking here, learning from others questions. Thanks for all the answers. Now I need to ask one. Using sqlite3 and other tools, I have been able to massage two very large .txt files into .csv and then into databases. 7000+/- rows each. And I have been successful at scripting the process. I am able to search for and compare 'commodities' that I know about just fine, but I need to be able to search for the commodities that I don't know about that meet criteria. In the simplified examples below, I need to compare the US and EU markets. There are a bunch of columns I don't yet care about (2, 4 in the example). The vertical order of columns are not as alphabetical as is my example, Barley could come after Corn as it does in EU. I can ask for Corn and see that the US price is lower than the EU price. But I might not know about Hemp today. What I'd like is a search that will reveal all similar names in table1,col3 and table2,col3 and show me the following output, ignoring non common names.

```
US  Barley  3.50
EU  Barley  3.51
US  Corn    6.51
EU  Corn    8.52
US  Hemp    8.23
EU  Hemp    4.15
```

The US/EU ordering is of far less importance than the commodities and their prices. Thanks in advance for your time and thoughts. Al

Database:Commodities

```
Table1
US  Foo Barley  3.50    abc
US  Bar Corn    6.51    def
US  Rev Flax    2.75    ghi
US  Des Hemp    8.23    jkl
US  Pon L_Rice  11.14   mno

Table2
EU  Pon Acai    4.25    pqr
EU  Rev Corn    8.52    stu
EU  Foo Barley  3.51    vwx
EU  Des Hemp    4.15    zab
EU  Bar S_Rice  11.13   cde
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have just one table. You can simulate this with a view

```
create view commodities as 
   select market, foo, commodity, price, bar from Table1
   union all
   select market, foo, commodity, price, bar from Table2
```

To get your specific result, try:

```
select market, commodity, price from commodities
where commodity in ('Barley', 'Corn', 'Hemp')
order by market, commodity
```

To get the result requested in your comment.

```
select c1.market, c1.commodity, c1.price from commodities c1, commodities c2
where c1.commodity = c2.commodity and abs(c1.price - c2.price) > 0.5  
order by c1.market, c1.commodity
```

Change `0.5` ro whatever price delta you are interested in seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your reply expects that I implicitly know in advance what commodities to look for. I don't and won't know. There are over 7000 line items, some of which I have no clue what they are, but if the delta in price between the two markets is sufficient, then I really want to know about that commodity on that day. As I stated in my initial query, I did not know about Hemp, thus would not know to add it to the search / select query.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Currie. I will take that down and work on it a bit. I'm not completely following the script at first blush, but I think I see what you're doing. Let me get my hands dirty a bit and if needed. I will post again. Thanks. Al

Answer (score 0):

MAJOR SUCCESS! Thank you. As you can see below, I have the script working almost perfectly with the small database. I've not tried it with the large one yet. One additional question about output formatting. Can I suppress the duplicate Commodity names in the final output?
Again, thank you for the help - I hope someone reads this and also gets value. Al
( yes, I cleaned it up a bit for readability )

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.6.21
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /test.db                    
sqlite> .tables
EUGoods  USGoods
sqlite> .headers on

sqlite> select * from USGoods;
Market|RegNo|Commodity|Price|Junk
"US"|234|"Barley"|3.5|"abc"
"US"|126|"Corn"|6.51|"def"
"US"|89|"Flax"|2.75|"ghi"
"US"|432|"Hemp"|8.23|"jkl"
"US"|813|"L_Rice"|11.14|"mno"

sqlite> select * from EUGoods;
Market|RegNo|Commodity|Price|Junk
"EU"|945|"Acai"|4.25|"pqr"
"EU"|111|"Corn"|8.52|"stu"
"EU"|44|"Barley"|3.51|"vwx"
"EU"|99|"Hemp"|4.15|"zab"
"EU"|339|"S_Rice"|11.13|"cde"

sqlite> SELECT USGoods.Commodity, 
EUGoods.Commodity, 
USGoods.Market, 
USGoods.Price, 
EUGoods.Market,
EUGoods.Price 
FROM USGoods , EUGoods 
WHERE USGoods.Commodity = EUGoods.Commodity;

Commodity|Commodity|Market|Price|Market|Price
"Barley"|"Barley"|"US"|3.5|"EU"|3.51
"Corn"|"Corn"|"US"|6.51|"EU"|8.52
"Hemp"|"Hemp"|"US"|8.23|"EU"|4.15

sqlite> SELECT USGoods.Commodity, 
EUGoods.Commodity, 
USGoods.Market, 
USGoods.Price, 
EUGoods.Market,
EUGoods.Price 
FROM USGoods , EUGoods 
WHERE USGoods.Commodity = EUGoods.Commodity 
AND abs(USGoods.Price - EUGoods.Price) > 0.5 
ORDER BY USGoods.market, USGoods.commodity;

Commodity|Commodity|Market|Price|Market|Price
"Corn"|"Corn"|"US"|6.51|"EU"|8.52
"Hemp"|"Hemp"|"US"|8.23|"EU"|4.15

sqlite>
```